# CentOS 7 i386 Netinstall error: 'Error setting up base repository"

Tags: centos, system-installation

I downloaded the 32-bit CentOS 7 Netinstall version from http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/i386/, and used the http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/os/i386/ as the repository during installation in virtualbox (Virtual machine RAM: 770MB, HDD: 8GB). I have already switched on the networks in the installation screen.

Whatever I try I am getting the same error: 'Error setting up base repository"

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 7.5 32-bit installed successfully for me using the following URL for the base repository (Installation Source):

http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/centos-altarch/7/os/i386/

You can also find the NetInstall and Minimal ISO images on this site at:

http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/centos-altarch/7/isos/i386/